# Transferring setup data to Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5

I am transferring setup data from a Droid Turbo to a Nexus 5 for Project Fi.

I'm not getting complete transfer of data (text messages) and want to try using a transfer cable between phones rather than the wi-fi based transfer.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[SyncDroid](http://www.sync-droid.com)** app in Android and computer to backup and restore using USB Cable..

Here's the official instructions:
**[How to Backup and Restore Android Phone with SyncDroid](http://www.sync-droid.com/syncdroid-getstarted.html)**

**Edit**: It's not possible to do that directly by connecting the 2 phones via USB cable, as you seem to ask for that in the question..

Comment: Edit2: requires a Windows computer ;)